# Solr. How can I configure DataImportHandler to get data through a proxy?

Tags: solr, proxy, dataimporthandler

I'm trying to import data from an XML using Dataimporthandler, but I get an "UnknownHostException". 
I'm preety sure this is because I need to configure proxy & credentials.

Does anybody know where to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're using `URLDataSource`. Looks like it doesn't support proxy for now, you can only configure a couple of timeouts.

You could extend it yourself adding the support for proxy, then you could even contribute it back to the community opening a [jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR) and attaching your own patch.